# Why Uppercase bucket names for S3 is allowed in US-EAST but not in other regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can anyone explain me why Uppercases is allowed in us-east but not in other regions?

[image: Details of S3 Uppercase]

link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer for your question is in the same link that you refer,

> DNS-compliant bucket names allow customers to benefit from new
>   features and operational improvements, as well as providing support
>   for virtual-host style access to buckets. **While the US East (N.
>   Virginia) Region currently allows non-compliant DNS bucket naming, we
>   are moving to the same DNS-compliant bucket naming convention for the
>   US East (N. Virginia) Region in the coming months**. This ensures a
>   single, consistent naming approach for Amazon S3 buckets.

US East is one of the oldest AWS regions and newer changes may take some time to get implemented for it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a legacy feature for backwards compatibility.

The us-east-1 region of S3 was the original S3 region.  It was designed with certain constraints, and Amazon doubtless learned a number of lessons as it operated for several years before additional regions were brought online.

Before other regions were added, the designers decided it made sense to impose additional constraints on the service -- but they could not add these constraints to us-east-1 without breaking existing customers and applications.

The requirement of lowercase-only bucket names seems obvious in retrospect, but with existing applications already using the service, this requirement couldn't be imposed on us-east-1.

There's a remark about these rules changing "in the coming months" on the page you referenced.  This may mean AWS will stop allowing such buckets to be created, but it seems unlikely that the old buckets would stop being accessible.

Interesting trivia: the S3 REST API has not had a breaking change in over 10 years.  All of the features that have been added over that time were implemented in such a way that existing applications that were unaware of those features should not have been affected.

This backwards compatibility appears to be at the heart of some of the S3 behaviors that seem otherwise confusing, such as the different bucket naming rules in us-east-1, why the regional endpoint is `s3-external-1` instead of `s3-us-east-1` or `s3.us-east-1`, and why the Location Constraint for buckets in that region is "empty string" and not `us-east-1`.

The region was formerly called "US Standard" throughout the documentation but subsequently renamed for consistency with the others.  Individual hostname entries in us-east-1's `*.s3.amazonaws.com` subdomain are actually automatically remapped to the endpoint of the specific region of any bucket that is created in a different region.   Nonexistent buckets follow a wildcard back to us-east-1.

Comment: Thank you Michael for providing detailed insight on this legacy exception which still prevails in US-EAST (N.Virginia) . Since the migration of S3 for all the old customers in US-EAST is virtually impossible, i assume that it will not be removed for near future.

Comment: I have no specific insights and I can't speak for AWS but it seems unlikely that they would make a breaking change like this... however, it's not unimaginable for them to eventually stop allowing creation of new buckets that violate the rules that have always been present in all the other regions.  There's a built-in motivation for anyone wanting to use any other region to use consistent naming practices, so the prevalence of this is difficult to speculate about.  Using DNS-incompatible bucket names should be avoided.